# Conditional Offer?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

In US graduate programs, what kind of conditions, usually, universities set, if they accept a student who has yet to finish his degree?

The obvious one is to finish before fall, but aside from this, how common is for them to set minimum GPA requirements?

For example, if a student has 3.6 GPA and is admitted, what kind of GPA should he maintain? Will a 3.55 be OK? How common is for programs to withdraw their offer on GPA basis?

I understand that this varies a lot, but please give me an idea of how it works in competitive programs.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve never seen specific grade or GPA targets mentioned as conditions for admission after acceptance.

I believe that the usual (informal) requirement is that your performance remain consistent with your previous performance. If your grade point average changes a little, no one is going to complain. However, if you contract a severe case of senioritis and barely pass your final-semester classes, that will definitely raise some alarms, regardless of how hig( your GPA was beforehand.